# I want to handle error state in Form.Item Ant design. how to handle disable button?

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, error-handling, antd

I spend almost 1 week to solve this problem.

I want to disable the button while the field gets an error.
Somehow always the `form.getFieldsError()` gets Array(0), even the error message `this is required` or `should be 7 digit` was showed up.

If you have any idea please help me.

this is my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Input, Button } from 'antd';
import { MinusCircleOutlined, PlusOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const DynamicFieldSet = () => {
  const MAX = 3;
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const onValuesChange = (changedValues, allValues) => {
    console.log(allValues.lines);
  };

  console.log(
    // this is always true
    form.getFieldsError().filter(({ errors }) => errors.length).length === 0
  );

  return (
    <Form
      initialValues={{ lines: [''] }}
      onValuesChange={onValuesChange}
      form={form}
      name={'lines'}
    >
      <Form.List name={'lines'}>
        {(fields, { add, remove }, { errors }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {fields.map((field, index) =>
                index < MAX ? (
                  <Form.Item required={false} key={field.key}>
                    <Form.Item
                      {...field}
                      validateTrigger={['onChange', 'onBlur']}
                      rules={[
                        {
                          required: true,
                          message: 'this is required',
                        },
                        {
                          min: 7,
                          max: 7,
                          message: 'should be 7 digit',
                        },
                      ]}
                      noStyle
                    >
                      <Input
                        placeholder=""
                        style={{ width: '50%' }}
                        type="number"
                      />
                    </Form.Item>
                    {index === 0 ? (
                      <>
                        <PlusOutlined
                          onClick={() => {
                            add();
                          }}
                        />
                      </>
                    ) : index === MAX - 1 ? (
                      <MinusCircleOutlined onClick={() => remove(field.name)} />
                    ) : (
                      <>
                        <PlusOutlined
                          onClick={() => {
                            add();
                          }}
                        />
                        <MinusCircleOutlined
                          onClick={() => remove(field.name)}
                        />
                      </>
                    )}
                  </Form.Item>
                ) : null
              )}
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>
      <Form.Item>
        <Button disabled={false} htmlType="submit">
          Send
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default DynamicFieldSet;
```

Comment: Refer to this sample https://codesandbox.io/s/ie2px

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really sure why but `form.getFieldsError()` is just not going to work. In order to achieve what you need, you should try using `form.validateFields()` instead.
The validateFields method, returns a promise that shows all the fields' data or errors on them:

```
form.validateFields()
    .then(values => {
        // Do something with values
    })
    .catch(errors => {
        // Do something with errors;
    });
```

Note that this will validate all the fields that you haven't even touched, causing all the provided error messages of all the fields to be shown. So, in case you want to validate just one field or so, all you need to do is to provide an array of field's names like ['myInput'].

From here, just create a new state to be set when errors appear and use it to show/hide-enable/disable your button.